# SDL2 で日本語フォントを使用すると、文字に重なった四角形が表示されてしまう

Tags: c++

はじめまして、コードの初心者です。SDL2でゲームを作り勉強始めました。LazyFoo sdl を参考に使っていました。

ゲーム風に一文字ずつ表したいですが、日本語のフォントでは変な四角形がありました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

でも英語の方は大丈夫でした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

他のフォントも試しましたがダメでした。

普通の文は問題がありません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

いい解決方法がないでしょうか？それとも別のやり方がないでしょうか？
これ修正出来ないなら別の方法でゲーム風に一文字ずつ表すことができますか？

使っているOSはFedora32です。

---

#### ソースコード

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h> 
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

const int win_w = 800;
const int win_h = 600;

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;

TTF_Font *font;

class Layer
{
   public:
        Layer()
        {
            mTexture = NULL;
            mWidth = 0;
            mHeight = 0;
        }
    
        ~Layer()
        {
            free();
        }
    
        void free()
        {
            if (mTexture != NULL)
            {
                SDL_DestroyTexture(mTexture);
                mTexture = NULL;
                mWidth = 0;
                mHeight = 0; 
            }
        }
    
        SDL_Texture *loadText(std::string Text, SDL_Color textColor)
        {
            free();
        
            SDL_Surface *textSurface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, Text.c_str(), textColor);
            mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, textSurface);
        
            mWidth = textSurface->w;
            mHeight = textSurface->h;
        
            SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
        
            return mTexture;            
        }
     
        void render(int x, int y)
        {
            SDL_Rect render_rect = {x, y, mWidth, mHeight};
        
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, mTexture, NULL, &render_rect);
        }

    private:
        SDL_Texture *mTexture;
        int mWidth;
        int mHeight;
};

Layer lyrText;

void run_text(std::string text, int x, int y)
{
    std::string container;

    SDL_Color textColor = {0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        SDL_Delay(100);
        container += text[i];
        lyrText.loadText(container, textColor);
        lyrText.render(x, y);
    
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    } 
}

void init()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    TTF_Init();

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("text", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, win_w, win_h, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
}

void init_load()
{
    font = TTF_OpenFont("./Fonts/GenShinM.ttf", 28);
}

void close()
{
    lyrText.free();

    TTF_CloseFont(font);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    TTF_Quit();
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    init();
    init_load();

    SDL_Event event;
    int quit = 0;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    run_text("私の名前は。。。", 200, 300);
    run_text("これは日本語フォント", 400, 200);

    while (quit == 0)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = 1;
            }
        }
    }
 
    close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デバッガ(gdb)で `run_text()` 関数の内部処理を調べてみます。

```sh
$ lsb_release -ir
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    20.04
$ uname -srm
Linux 5.4.0-51-generic x86_64
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) 10.2.0

$ g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g show_message.cc -o show_message -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
$ gdb show_message
(gdb) break run_text
(gdb) run
Starting program: ...
Thread 1 "..." hit Breakpoint 1, run_text (
           :
(gdb) set charset UTF-8
(gdb) p text
$10 = "私の名前は。。。"
(gdb) p text.length()
$11 = 24
(gdb) set charset ASCII
(gdb) p (char *)text
$15 = 0x555555e2f020 "\347\247\201\343\201\256\345\220\215\345\211\215\343\201\257\343\200\202\343\200\202\343\200\202"
```

UTF-8 encoding の文字列「私の名前は。。。」の「長さ」は `24`(= 3bytes * 8文字) になっていることが判るかと思います。実際には、「私の名前は。。。」の「文字列長」は `8` であることが期待されているはずです。

そこで、`UTF-8`(内部表現は可変長) <-> `UTF-16`(内部表現は固定長)への変換を行なうことで解決する方法が考えられます。

```cpp
#include <codecvt> 
#include <locale>


void run_text(std::string text, int x, int y)
{
    std::string container;
    SDL_Color textColor = {.r = 0, .g = 0, .b = 0, .a = 0};
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    for (auto && c : converter.from_bytes(text)) { // UTF-8 -> UTF-16
        SDL_Delay(100);
        // UTF-16 -> UTF-8
        container += converter.to_bytes(c);
        lyrText.loadText(container, textColor);
        lyrText.render(x, y);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    } 
}
```

[image: show_message]

Comment: 本当にありがとうございます。